# How to get List of users and total from Auth0 using Python

Tags: python, auth0

How can I get the list of all users from an Auth0 Account and also get the total using PYTHON language?

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 allows using an API token to obtain data.  To obtain the user details including the total, you will need the API client secret and id.

[Auth0 document to get the token](https://auth0.com/docs/security/tokens/access-tokens/get-access-tokens#:%7E:text=To%20get%20an%20access%20token,language%20and%20framework%2Dspecific%20SDKs.)

I've written an article [here](https://www.smart5.co.uk/en_gb/article/27/how-to-get-the-list-of-users-from-auth0-using-python)

The code to use...

```
import http.client
import json

client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
business_name = 'xxxxxxxxx'

# GET THE ACCESS TOKEN using the client_id and client_secret
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(business_name+".eu.auth0.com")
payload = "{\"client_id\":\""+client_id+"\",\"client_secret\":\""+client_secret+"\",\"audience\":\"https://"+business_name+".eu.auth0.com/api/v2/\",\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"}"
headers = { 'content-type': "application/json" }
conn.request("POST", "/oauth/token", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
tokendetails_json = data.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
# Load the JSON to a Python list & dump it back out as formatted JSON
tokendetails = json.loads(tokendetails_json)


#NOW GET THE USERS AND TOTAL
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(business_name+".eu.auth0.com")
payload = "{\"client_id\":\""+client_id+"\",\"client_secret\":\""+client_secret+"\",\"audience\":\"https://"+business_name+".eu.auth0.com/api/v2/\",\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"}"
headers = { 'content-type': "application/json","Authorization": "Bearer "+tokendetails['access_token'] }
conn.request("GET", "/api/v2/users?include_totals=true", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
result_data_json = data.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')

# Load the JSON to a Python list & dump it back out as formatted JSON
result_data = json.loads(result_data_json)
print(result_data)                  # Json list of all users
print(result_data['total'])         # Just the count of total users
```

Answer (score 0):

Got [sydadder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252237/sydadder) code to work after enabling a test application and then giving read permissions here:
Auth0 dashboard / Applications / APIs / Machine to Machine Applications / Auth0 Management API (Test Application) (expand by clicking on down-arrow)

Without adjusting permissions I got:

```
{'statusCode': 401, 'error': 'Unauthorized', 'message': 'Invalid token', 'attributes': {'error': 'Invalid token'}}
```

Plus altering "eu.auth0.com" throughout to the appropriate Auth0 region.